# angularjs nested cascading directive for dropdown

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to create a cascading dropdown directive .

```
<my-dropdown label="states" url="http://statelisturl">    
   <my-dropdown label="cities" url="http://citylisturl">
   </my-dropdown>
</my-dropdown>
```

But states will be list first, when I select a state cities will be get from url.

Is this possible for angularjs technically? Or I should be seperated directive for every dropdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
.directive("myDropdown", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        require: ["myDropdown", "?^^myDropdown"],
        template: "<select ng-options='opt as opt.label for opt in $ctrl.options' ng-model='$ctrl.selectedOption' ng-change='$ctrl.changed($ctrl.selectedOption)'></select><div ng-transclude></div>",
        scope: true,
        bindToController: {
            url: "@",
            label: "@"
        },
        controller: function($scope, $http) {
            var _self = this;
            _self.init = function() {
                $http.get(_self.url).then(function(response) {
                    _self.options = response.data;
                });
            }
            _self.parentChanged = function(item) {
                var id = item.id;
                $http.get(_self.url + "?id=" + id).then(function(response) {
                    _self.options = response.data;
                });
            }
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
            var ctrl = ctrls[0];
            var parentCtrl = ctrls[1];

            if (parentCtrl) {
                scope.$watch(function() {
                    return parentCtrl.selectedOption;
                }, function(newval) {
                    if (newval) {
                        ctrl.parentChanged(newval);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                ctrl.init();
            }
        },
        controllerAs: "$ctrl",
        transclude: true
    }
});
```

**EDIT**: I have a working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kgub1gk6/2/)

Comment: I have several questions, why use ["myDropdown", "?^^myDropdown"].

Comment: The first one requires the controller of the directive itself, so it can be used in the `link` function. The second one is used for requiring the parent `my-dropdown` directive. If it isn't null, it means there is a parent so it can watch its selected item

Comment: I want to generate dynamically nested directives. is this possible? Data will be javascript object of nested directive. and generate `ng-repead` or another way?